# Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent

Tags: r

I have an image with 4 channels and I separate each channel into a separate file. When I combine them into one plus NDVI, why does rasterstack show an error? Whereas in other images stacking can be done.
This is the information about my data

```
> diff_ndvi_1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 9219, 9280, 85552320  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 667737, 695577, 68127, 95784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -0.8249686, 1.061913  (min, max)

> imgdif_1_2
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 9219, 9279, 85543101, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 667740, 695577, 68127, 95784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer 
min values : -6226 
max values :  5012 

> imgdif_1_4
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 9219, 9280, 85552320, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 667737, 695577, 68127, 95784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer 
min values : -6475 
max values :  6590 

> imgdif_1_6
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 9219, 9280, 85552320, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 667737, 695577, 68127, 95784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer 
min values : -7441 
max values :  9369 

> imgdif_1_8
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 9219, 9280, 85552320, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 667737, 695577, 68127, 95784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer 
min values : -5951 
max values : 10349
```

I've tried restarting from scratch and looking at the extents and projection system via QGIS but the result is the same, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your `imgdif_1_2` has one pixel less (dimensions : 9219, 9279) as comapred to other rsaters (dimensions : 9219, 9280). Thats why it shows the error. You can use `resample` function to resample it to the same dimension.

Comment: @UseR10085 Ahhhh My bad. It turns out that I wasn't careful enough, the layer turned out to be 1 pixel different. Thanks for your answer